# Как пофиксить вылеты в приложении Android в определенных ситуациях?

Tags: android, java, исключения, многопоточность

Всем доброго времени суток! Недавно заинтересовался разработкой приложений под Android (до этого был опыт программирования консольных программ на C++ и визуальных проектов на C#). Первым проектом решил выбрать игру, которую полгода назад писал на C# для Windows. За основу взял [статью](http://dajver.blogspot.com/2012/01/android-1-surfaceview.html) из одного блога. Игровое активити у меня полностью занимает SurfaceView, на котором и происходит вся отрисовка. А вот за "движок" отвечает отдельный поток (Thread). Структура этого всего подробнее описана в самой статье.

За три дня я закончил работу над игрой, и всё вроде бы работает, но есть одна серьёзная неприятность. Игра *иногда* вылетает при выходе (конкретнее - при закрытии игрового активити) и **всегда** вылетает, если через меню многозадачности свернуть и развернуть её (опять же, если активно именно игровое активити).

При вылете игра возвращает *IllegalThreadStateException*. Помогите разобраться, где я напартачил. Основная часть исходника "движкового" потока:

**UPD. Проблема с вылетом через многозадачность решена (спасибо [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd)).** Проблема с вылетом при выходе тоже не наблюдалась.

Comment: а что показывает стектрейс в logcat ?

Comment: @KoVadim,
http://cs425728.vk.me/v425728907/4725/NKN2F1h0Zbs.jpg
http://pastebin.com/dz7AbAV1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хм, ну вроде бы понятно. У вас `surfaceCreated` вызывается много раз, а вы каждый раз запускаете поток. Рискну предположить, что вы не можете перезапустить поток, вам надо убивать его в `surfaceDestroyed` и создавать новый в `surfaceCreated`.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, проблема с вылетом при сворачивании-разворачивании решилась!
Действительно, логично создавать новый поток, ведь все игровые переменные у меня хранятся в GameView. Я почему-то думал, что игра будет сбрасываться и начинаться "с нуля".

Comment: Пожалуйста!